# Why does Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED change the generated select statement(s)?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Here is the code which is testing `getAll()` method:

```
@DisplayName("Book dao methods must")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BookRepositoryJpa.class)
@EntityScan(basePackages = "dz6.model")
@Transactional//(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class BookDaoJpaTest {
    @Autowired
    private BookRepositoryJpa repo;
    @Test
    @DisplayName("return book list of the correct size")
    public void shouldReturnBookListWithCorrectSize() {
        IntStream.range(0, 10).forEachOrdered(i -> {
            Book b = new Book(String.format("Book %d", i));
            b.setAuthor(new Author(String.format("Author %d", i)));
            b.setGenre(new Genre(String.format("Genre %d", i)));
            repo.insert(b);
        });
        assertEquals(10, repo.getAll().size());
    }
}
```

When `(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` is commented as shown above, the `getAll()` generates the following sql in the console:

```
Hibernate: select book0_.id as id1_1_, book0_.author_id as author_i3_1_, book0_.genre_id as genre_id4_1_, book0_.name as name2_1_ from book book0_
```

But if I uncomment it, there appear many additional select statements:

```
Hibernate: select book0_.id as id1_1_, book0_.author_id as author_i3_1_, book0_.genre_id as genre_id4_1_, book0_.name as name2_1_ from book book0_
Hibernate: select author0_.id as id1_0_0_, author0_.name as name2_0_0_ from author author0_ where author0_.id=?
Hibernate: select genre0_.id as id1_3_0_, genre0_.name as name2_3_0_ from genre genre0_ where genre0_.id=?
Hibernate: select author0_.id as id1_0_0_, author0_.name as name2_0_0_ from author author0_ where author0_.id=?
Hibernate: select genre0_.id as id1_3_0_, genre0_.name as name2_3_0_ from genre genre0_ where genre0_.id=?
Hibernate: select author0_.id as id1_0_0_, author0_.name as name2_0_0_ from author author0_ where author0_.id=?
Hibernate: select genre0_.id as id1_3_0_, genre0_.name as name2_3_0_ from genre genre0_ where genre0_.id=?
Hibernate: select author0_.id as id1_0_0_, author0_.name as name2_0_0_ from author author0_ where author0_.id=?
Hibernate: select genre0_.id as id1_3_0_, genre0_.name as name2_3_0_ from genre genre0_ where 
....
```

I know they can be fixed with `join fetch`. The question is why the commented `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED` also changes the behaviour. 
Here is `getAll()` method:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class BookRepositoryJpa implements BookRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    public List<Book> getAll() {
        Query query=em.createQuery("select a from Book a");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
//...
}
```

The book:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")

    private UUID id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Genre genre;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)

   private Author author;
   //...
}
```

Comment: "I know they can be fixed with join fetch" have you tested that? Because I don't think this is true.

Comment: Why not? select b from Book b join fetch b.author a join fetch b.genre g eleminates additional selects from genre and author.

Comment: Not inserts, but select (getall) generates these additional selects.

Answer (score 0):

With `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED` you are basically disabling transactions which should be similar to have not `@Transactional` annotation at all.
This in turn means that each interaction with the repository will start a new transaction along with a new session.

Therefor when you `insert` the book it has to merge the referenced entities which triggers the select statements.